# View pager holds old fragment after rotate screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a view pager, with 4 fragments. (im using FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Each fragment have a "FrameLayout/ container", where i add and replace many fragments.

Everything works fine, but when i change screen orientation, **the first fragment of the line is restored Over actual fragment. Then both appears at same time.**

Im putting a picture with a example of what happens:

[First Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7X3V.png)

[Second Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn3FZ.png)

[when i rotate screen]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxaVn.png
```

My MainActivity Code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


val numPages = 4
var pager: ViewPager? = null
private val TITLES = arrayOf("Feed", "Catalogo","Guia","Rendimento")
var menuImages:Array<ImageView>?=null
var menuTexts:Array<TextView>?=null

var fragments = arrayListOf<Fragment>()


private var fragmentCreated1: FeedContainerFragment? = null
private var fragmentCreated2: CatalogContainerFragment? = null
private var fragmentCreated3: GuideContainerFragment? = null
private var fragmentCreated4: TestContainerFragment? = null



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_default)


     fragments.add(FeedContainerFragment())
     fragments.add(CatalogContainerFragment())
     fragments.add(GuideContainerFragment())
     fragments.add(TestContainerFragment())


    menuImages= arrayOf(findViewById(R.id.icon_feed) as ImageView,
                        findViewById(R.id.icon_catalogue) as ImageView,
                        findViewById(R.id.icon_guide) as ImageView,
                        findViewById(R.id.icon_form) as ImageView)

    menuTexts= arrayOf(findViewById(R.id.text_feed) as TextView,
                    findViewById(R.id.text_catalogue) as TextView,
                    findViewById(R.id.text_guide) as TextView,
                    findViewById(R.id.text_form) as TextView)




    menuImages?.get(0)?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.colorAccent))
    menuTexts?.get(0)?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.colorAccent))


    //view pager

    pager = findViewById(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
    val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)


    pager?.adapter = pagerAdapter
    pager?.offscreenPageLimit = 4


    pager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            pager?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            repaintMenuDefaultColor()

            menuImages?.get(position)?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.colorAccent))
            menuTexts?.get(position)?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.colorAccent))

        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

        }
    })


    //Navigation Menus
    MenuUtils.generateMaterialMenu(this)
    MenuUtils.generateBottomMenu(this, this.pager!!)


}

private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return numPages
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when(position) {
            0->return FeedContainerFragment()
            1->return CatalogContainerFragment()
            2->return GuideContainerFragment()
            3->return TestContainerFragment()

            else->return FeedContainerFragment()
        }

    }


    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return TITLES[position]
    }

    override fun getItemPosition(obj: Any?): Int {

        if (obj is Refreshable) {
            return POSITION_NONE
        }
        return super.getItemPosition(obj)
    }



    override fun instantiateItem(container:ViewGroup, position:Int):Any {
        val createdFragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position) as Fragment
        when (position) {
            0 -> fragmentCreated1 = createdFragment as FeedContainerFragment
            1 -> fragmentCreated2 = createdFragment as CatalogContainerFragment
            2 -> fragmentCreated3 = createdFragment as GuideContainerFragment
            3 -> fragmentCreated4 = createdFragment as TestContainerFragment

        }


        return createdFragment
    }

}


override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}


fun repaintMenuDefaultColor(){
    this.menuImages?.map {
        it.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.menu_icon))
    }

    this.menuTexts?.map {
        it.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(baseContext,R.color.menu_text))
    }


}
```

}

Any Help is Welcome !

EDIT: Actually, what is happening is that ViewPager keep the Actual Fragment as a "Ghost" and then restore the First Fragment of the line.

**Is there a way to clean the screen and remove that "Ghost" ?**

**EDIT 2: Found the solution.** I needed to verify if a instance of fragment already exists before add the fragment on each "container"
The problem wasn't on ViewPager, or Adapter.  Every time i change the orientation a new fragment was included.

So, just put the verification below :

```
     if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        activity
                .supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerGuide, YourFragment())
                .commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When Rotating Screen the Activity and the Fragments are recreated so its start from position 0..

1. Save Fragment position when viewpager is rebuild just choose the Fragment you need.
2. Check out this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html
3. Disable screen Rotations.

Comment: The fragment is recreated from position 0 but unfortunately the Actual Fragment is held as  "ghost" ... is there a a way to force a "clean" repaint of the screen ?